Are all arguments for the existence of other minds circular?
The argument from analogy and the best explanation argument (IBE) rely on the claim that my mental states are responsible for my behavior and then conclude that the behavior of other people is caused by mental states, as in my case.
Does this reference to one's own case make these arguments circular? If not, give an example of what these arguments should look like to be cyclic.
What should the justification of belief in the existence of other minds look like so that it is not circular?
Thank you

They're not necessarily circular, but they probably necessarily have uncertain axiomatic assumptions, like just about everything

I don't see any circularity at all. How does "my behavior is determined by my mental states" presuppose "other people have mental states"? How can a claim about me presuppose a claim about people who are not me?

All arguments eventually become circular, because straight lines do not occur naturally in the known universe. Linearity is theoretical. The question is the diameter of the circle. In this case the circle is the diameter of one single perspective, so it is in fact very likely to emerge as circular early in the consideration.

"My mind exists, therefore, a mind exists" is circular, the conclusion restates the premise with some details removed. "My mind exists, therefore, other minds exist" is not circular, the conclusion does not restate the premise. Analogical arguments are generally non-circular, as they analogize something to something else.

Tell me, what should a cyclical argument in favor of the existence of other minds look like? I want to understand for the future how it is not necessary to formulate arguments in favor of the existence of other minds.

It is to me concentric as well as circular.  To say my mind exists applies the premise to the conclusion, although there is really no way to escape it.  Therefore, to say my mind exists therefore your mind exists is the same argument.  Better to say that I perceive my mind exists and that you tell me that you perceive that your mind exists, so indications are minds exists.  It cuts enough out of the circles to be able to talk about other subjects.

I suspect my mind exists, but I do so with my mind.  There is no independent verification.  I perceive that you suspect your mind exists.  Alternatives considered to why our perceptions are that minds exist have added no value.   Indications are minds exist.  Indications are tricky.  Based on indications, Bigfoot is a two-foot-tall invisible nocturnal monopod, capable of leaping one hundred meters.  Indications being large, isolated footprints in an environment that is unlikely to be able to support and provide sustained cover for a twelve-foot-tall creature. Yet there is the footprint.

We do not know whether the mental processes of other persons cause their behaviour similarly to my mental processes causing my behaviour.

But other people belong to the same species. In general, they act
similar to me in similar situations – subtracting differences of
their character. Hence the most simple hypothesis: Yes, also their
behaviour is caused by their mental processes.
In first approximation, there is no fact which contradicts this hypothesis. In second approximation, specific differences in behaviour are ascribed to character differences, hence to different mental processes. Those are studied by psychology, e.g., by personality psychology, and under certain circumstances also by neuroscience.

My answer is similar to your analogy principle. The argument is not
circular, but I am emphasizing the hypothetical character of this
generalization, which is supported by observation and common evolutionary
descent.


Aside: I do not know the principle of "the best explanation argument".
